"There are no components in DLL that can be placed on toolbox" hapends in vs 2022
I have a custom control that I am trying to add to toolbox. The name of the file is xxx.dll and I go through the procedure of right click in Toolbox > Choose Items and then selecting the file after browsing to it under .NET Framework components.
I however get this error message:

There are no components in that can be placed on toolbox

Why do I get this message and how can I resolve it?
what I have trid：

1）open Windows explorer and navigate to the DLL；drag the DLL and drop
it on Visual Studio in the Toolbox, exactly where you want your
components to appear. This didn't work.
2)open Windows explorer and navigate to the DLL;copy the dll file and
paste it directly on the toolbox tab you wish to place the controls.
This didn't work.
3)Check the visibility of the custom classes. I declared them as
public
4)sum up, There is a same problem
text,
but the anwser didn't work.



The mismatching of win32 dependencies and win64 vs2022 results
in this problem.The dll file have some win32 dependencies, which is
not supported in vs 2022 that is win64 process.What I should do is
to use win64 dependencies in this dll file.
About The closed question, I have tried to update the vs 2022.
Then the form design mode worked well. The latest version of vs 2022
has been adding support for .NET Framework projects in Windows
Forms out-of-process designer to solve the problem. The link is
hereout-of-process designer . And This link may help you understanding further
However, The 32-bit resembly still can't be added into the toolbox as component in vs 2022(64-bit).

